# How to install python on empty alpine container

Tags: python, docker, shell, alpine-linux

I need to install python on running container, based empty alpine image.
That is my run command:

```
docker run -it alpine:3.14 sh
```

And then I get a shell, like this:

```
/ #
```

Then, i want to install python

```
/ # apt-get update -y
/ # apt-get install -y python
```

But I get this error:

```
sh: apt-get: not found
```

I try to install bash by those commands but it doesn't work

```
/ # apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.14.2-40-gf566f645a9 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main]
v3.14.2-42-gf168ad374f [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community]
OK: 14938 distinct packages available
/ # apk upgrade
OK: 6 MiB in 14 packages
/ # apk add bash
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20210612-r0)
(2/4) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20210612-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.1.0-r0)
(4/4) Installing bash (5.1.4-r0)
Executing bash-5.1.4-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r3.trigger
OK: 8 MiB in 18 packages
/ # bash
bash-5.1# apt-get update -y
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

My question is: is it possible to install python on shell?

P.S: I must do it in the container and must use in empty alpine image

Thanks!!

Comment: I looked up [alpine package manager](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=alpine+package+manager) and the first hit indicates that `apk` is the typical manager, have you tried `apk add python`? or more likely `apk update` followed by `add python`

Comment: As others have said, you are not using the right package manager. On the other hand, if it suits your needs, there are Python-Alpine pre-built images. Find the appropriate tags here: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: There is official docker image for python using alpine already. Why not just use that instead?

Comment: Remember that anything you do in an interactive shell in a container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  You probably want to do this sort of setup in a Dockerfile, to build a reusable image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` is Debian/Ubuntu's package manager. On Alpine you need to stick with `apk`, the Alpine package manager.

If you run across Docker guides that use `apt-get` you can't run the commands directly. You need to look up the equivalent package names and use `apk`.

```
# apk update
# apk add python3
```